# How to get this name with id after click submit button?

Tags: php, html, submit, form-submit

The below code I use input name result+row id and Its working as expected.

```
<td class="t-width-150" id="result">
   <input type="text" name="result<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" id="txtresult" value="0">
</td>
```

Now I want to get this name with id in another page after clicking submit button. What should I use in below code:

```
<td class="t-width-150">
  <?php echo $_POST['result']; ?>
</td>
```

Thank you!

**Update: I solved it. Don't need more answers. Thank you, everyone!**

Comment: You would have to use the actual name of the field - with `name="result123"`, you would need to access `$_POST['result123']`. You should rather make this something like `name="result[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]"` to begin with - then `$_POST['result']` will be an array you can easily loop over.

Comment: @misorude I can't use name="result123" because I want to use row id after "result" from the MySql database. And upper code is not a problem the problem is here "$_POST['result']". How I get name="result<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" into "$_POST['result']".

Comment: _“How I get name="result<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" into "$_POST['result']"”_ - you would have to do that yourself. `name="result123"` will cause `$_POST['result123']` to come into existence - that is simply how this stuff works. There is no magic that would automatically make this available as `$_POST['result']`.

Comment: _“I can't use name="result123" because”_ - that _is_ what you are currently using. _“because I want to use row id after "result" from the MySql database”_ - and how would that be stopping you from using what I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a form field naming format like this:

```
name="result[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]"
```

So effectively, this will result in field names like `result[1]`, `result[2]`, `result[5]` (the ids do not need to be consecutive or in order for this.)

PHP will then generate an array out of this in `$_POST['result']`, that you can loop over using the extended foreach syntax, to get access to both your row id and the submitted value:

```
foreach( $_POST['result'] as $id => $value ) {
  echo "The submitted value for the record with ID ", $id, " was ", $value, "<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you don't know in advance what POST variables there will be, because there is an unknown number of results, and therefore an unknown number of textboxes, in the form? If so then you could either

a) Loop through all the `$_POST` variables to find any which start with "result" and then extract the value from it e.g.

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key)
{
  if (preg_match("/result(\d+)/", $key, $matches))
  {
    echo $_POST[$key]; //will get the value entered in the input field
    echo $matches[1]; //will get you the row ID from the field name e.g. from "result123" it would return "123".
  }
}
```

Or

b) use array-syntax in the form field names, and have the result and ID fields separate e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="result[]" id="txtresult" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="rowID[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
```

and then in PHP you'd loop through `$_POST["result"]` and then examine the matching index in `$_POST["rowID"]`, which will be arrays, to relate the result together.

Comment: I still think `name="result[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]"` is the way to go here. That way, the IDs will automatically become the indices of the array in `$_POST['result']`, so looping over that with the extended foreach syntax gives easy access to both row ID and entered field values.

Comment: @misorude a catch with that explicit numbering approach is that if the ID values are not consecutive (and/or don't start with 0) then unfortunately some browsers will not submit all the values. Clearly if this is based on database data then there's a very high likelihood of both of those scenarios occurring. If you want to go down the array-syntax approach it's better to use `[]` and let the browser handle the numbering.

Comment: Never heard of that before. Can’t see how that problem should even occur in the first place - the browser is not interpreting these names to mean anything to begin with, and all the magic of creating the array based on these parameter names, is purely on the PHP side of things. Do you have any link where that alleged problem is described in more detail, or what browsers would be affected?

Comment: @misorude apologies. You're right it's not a browser issue. Having done a bit of reading, that was a bit of a faulty recollection. It appears to be specific to ASP.NET MVC where the _server-side_ code doesn't parse the submitted form values correctly in those scenarios. I'm not even sure it's still an issue in the latest versions. So if I were you I'd go ahead and post your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Ah, that’s a relief :-) I was afraid for a second, that older projects were I used this, would have to be tested for any such issues now.